# UWP - how can I test a closing of app when trial are expired with CurrentAppSimulator?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a problem with trial period in my app and I tried to reproduce it in the test mode.

I want to test the following behaviour:

1. App has trial period of 1 day.
2. The user opens the app a day later, when trial is expired.

According to this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219685.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the message dialog will be shown.

When I tried testing this scenario, I found the file called `%userprofile%\AppData\local\packages\<package name>\LocalState\Microsoft\Windows Store\ApiData\WindowsStoreProxy.xml`.

This file contains:

```
<LicenseInformation>
        <App>
            <IsActive>false</IsActive>
            <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
        </App>
........
</LicenseInformation>
```

In this case my app is open. But look at the behaviour when I check a license using this code:

```
LicenseInformation^ licenseInfo = CurrentAppSimulator::LicenseInformation;
if( !licenseInfo->IsActive )
{
   //I get into the code section
}
```

But my app still opens successfully.

Will my app be closed by the OS in this case, when I publish it in Store and load with Store (with  `Windows::ApplicationModel::Store::CurrentApp` and according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219685.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))?

How can I simulate this closing (by the OS)?